# Prepare VGG Perceptual Loss on the fly for super-resolution with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Basically I am implementing the same model for single image super-resolution from the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08155. I ran into memory issue when I tried to generate to activation output of the ground truth patches, which will be used to compute the perceptual loss during the training. I wonder how I can generate the outputs on the fly.

I use 10k 288x288 image patches as ground truths and the corresponding blurred and down-sampled 72x72 patches as training data. For the loss network I use VGG-16 and the output from Relu2-2 layer. I tried to use model.predict() to feed in the ground truth patches and generate the corresponding activation outputs, which can then be passed to model.fit() for training. However the data-set seems to be too large and it ran into memory issue. I understand it is a common problem in real practice with data-set being too large, and the solution is to use fit.generator() and imagedataGenrator to generate data on the fly. However I am not sure how exactly I can implement such function in my case. Could someone explain to me how I should implement such function or what other methods should I adopt to handle this problem?

```py
### Create Image Transformation Model ###
mainModel = ResnetBuilder.build((3,72,72), 5, basic_block, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

### Create Loss Model (VGG16) ###
lossModel = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(288,288,3))
lossModel.trainable=False
for layer in lossModel.layers:
    layer.trainable=False

### Create New Loss Model (Use Relu2-2 layer output for perceptual loss)
lossModel = Model(lossModel.inputs,lossModel.layers[5].output)
lossModelOutputs = lossModel(mainModel.output)

### Create Full Model ###
fullModel = Model(mainModel.input, lossModelOutputs)

### Compile FUll Model
fullModel.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
trained_epochs=0
print("fullModel compiled!")
```

```py
y_train_lossModel = lossModel.predict(y_train,batch_size=1)
```

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-1f5c849e454a> in <module>
----> 1 y_train_lossModel = lossModel.predict(y_train,batch_size=1)
      2 print(y_train_lossModel.shape)
      3 with h5py.File('y_train_lossModel.h5', 'w') as hf:
      4     hf.create_dataset('y_train_lossModel', data=y_train_lossModel)

~/anaconda3/envs/fyp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1167                                             batch_size=batch_size,
   1168                                             verbose=verbose,
-> 1169                                             steps=steps)
   1170 
   1171     def train_on_batch(self, x, y,

~/anaconda3/envs/fyp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in predict_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
    298                 for batch_out in batch_outs:
    299                     shape = (num_samples,) + batch_out.shape[1:]
--> 300                     outs.append(np.zeros(shape, dtype=batch_out.dtype))
    301             for i, batch_out in enumerate(batch_outs):
    302                 outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out

MemoryError:
```

```py
### Train the full model
epochs=5
for n in range(trained_epochs+1,trained_epochs+epochs+1):
    print("Epoch",n)
    fullModel.fit(x_train, y_train_lossModel, batch_size=4, epochs=1)
    fullModel.save('full_model.h5')
trained_epochs=n
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for why you might go out of memory:

1. The model doesn't fit in your memory. If you are moving all the computation on the GPU, try to run them instead on the CPU. The CPU will require your model to be stored in RAM which is usually bigger the the GRAM. If that doesn't help, the only solution is to simplify your model (or upgrade your system, of course).

   2.The data doesn't fit in your memory. From your code, I have no idea what is the size of `x_train` . Generally, you don't give the whole training set as input to your data because it slows down your training (most of the gradients will be reduntant) and it doesn't necessary improves performance (it doesn't allow to escape from local optima). The solution here is to give your inputs in small portions called `mini-batches`. Hence, the code would be something like this:

   ```
   for n_epochs in range(num_epochs):
       x_batch, y_batch = getMiniBatch(x_train, y_train)
       model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
   ```